# HTML5 Video - timeupdate and scrubbing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html5-video

I have an HTML5 video which shows and plays after jquery drag and drop elements are in their correct slots.  While the video plays, I have a script which listens to the timeupdate on the video and changes the dragged elements background color to a highlight and then back to the original color depending on the time.

Now the issue is that when scrubbing the video say backwards after finished, the dragged elements are all highlighted when the code is:

```
function play_vid(){
$("#slots").addClass('left');
$( "#element1" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_1"});
$( "#element2" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_2"});
$( "#element3" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_3"});
$( "#element4" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_4"});
$( "#element5" ).position({my: "left top",at: "left top",of: "#slot_5"});
$(".video").show();
$("#v1").show();
v1.play();
document.getElementById('v1').addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
$("#element1").removeClass('correct');
$("#element1").addClass('highlighted');
if(this.currentTime > 15) {
$("#element1").removeClass('highlighted');
$("#element1").addClass('correct');
$("#element2").removeClass('correct');
$("#element2").addClass('highlighted');
}
    if(this.currentTime > 30) {
$("#element2").removeClass('highlighted');
$("#element2").addClass('correct');
$("#element3").removeClass('correct');
$("#element3").addClass('highlighted');
}
        if(this.currentTime > 45) {
$("#element3").removeClass('highlighted');
$("#element3").addClass('correct');
$("#element4").removeClass('correct');
$("#element4").addClass('highlighted');
}
            if(this.currentTime > 60) {
$("#element4").removeClass('highlighted');
$("#element4").addClass('correct');
$("#element5").removeClass('correct');
$("#element5").addClass('highlighted');
}
});
```

How can I make it so that scrubbing the video highlights only the elements as per the times above?

See Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/7YW59/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good solution, but as one option it might be easier to reason about this if you have a structure which explicitly lists what classes each element should have in a certain timespan.

```
var classesAtTime = {
    0 : { // starting at time 0 these elements should have these classes
        element1 : 'highlighted',
        element2 : '',
        element3 : ''
    },
    15 : { // starting at time 15 ...
        element1 : 'correct',
        element2 : 'highlighted',
        element3 : ''
    },
    30 : {
        element1 : 'highlighted',
        element2 : 'correct',
        element3 : 'highlighted'
    }
    // ... and so on
};
```

While that gets a bit long, it is easy to see what state you would be in at what time. Then in your timeupdate you could have something like this to pick which elements should have which classes at this point:

```
document.getElementById('v1').addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var neededClasses = {};
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.currentTime; i++) {
        neededClasses = classesAtTime[i];
    }

    // Go through elements
    for (var elementID in classesAtTime) {
        if (!classesAtTime.hasOwnProperty(elementID)) continue;
        $('#' + elementID).attr('class', neededClasses[elementID]);
    }
}
```

If something needed to have more than one class, you can list them as for example element1 : 'highlighted foo bar'.

Comment: Thanks for that Bemmu...that could certainly be a better way of handling things, but I'm not sure if that will help with the scubbing problem.  I have created a fiddle with your code but it's not changing the elements' classes...

Comment: Sorry, I should have used pseudocode or avoided including code. I was trying to just roughly demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bemmu...actually the solution was simply to remove the highlighted class for all elements that should not be highlighted at the time point in the video (not just the previous element).  So your idea of seperating the elements into time slots is worthy as the answer.  Still to implement your solution though...

See updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AYXmD/